# Two combobox with same ItemsSource of ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>

Tags: wpf, combobox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=optList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=optList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> optList{ get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>() {
new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "1"},
new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "2"}
}
```

When I am switching between comboboxes then one dropdown become empty. Do you know why? It is working with collection of String.

Comment: Don't do that, an `ObservableCollection` of `ComboBoxItem`s is ugly. Please read more about MVVM and how to separate the view from the model. To solve your error: use an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead.

Comment: I used ObservableCollection<string> and it works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBoxItem is a FrameworkElement which cannot belong to multiple parents.

When you use string collection, each ComboBox generate a new ComboBoxItem for the same string. When collection contains ComboBoxItems, comboBoxes *don't* create other ComboBoxItems and reuse existing, stealing them from each other.

Additionally when you follow MVVM approach, you should not have ComboBoxItem objects in a view model which provides binding source.

So string collection is a correct solution.