# C# WPF Binding two ListBoxes on TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, listboxitem

I would like to have a `TabControl` with two `TabItems` and one `Listbox` on each Item. I want both `ListBoxes` to show the same content and so I bound both to the same `ObservableCollection<T>`. At first the items are shown correctly in `Listbox1`. Also if i switch to `ListBox2` the Items show up here as well. If I go back to `Listbox1` afterwards all the items are gone and stay in `ListBox2`. I want both `ListBoxes` to hold and show the same `ListBoxItems` constantly. Really would appreciate some help!

My XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="350*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem Header="Test1">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Components}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test2">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Components}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

CS Code:

```
        private ListBoxItem _oBoxItem;
        private Int32 i = 0;
        private ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> components = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> Components
        {
            get
            {
                if (components == null)
                    components = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>();
                return components;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _oBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
            _oBoxItem.Content = "Part " + i.ToString();
            Components.Add(_oBoxItem);
            i += 1;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two combobox with same ItemsSource of ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524041/two-combobox-with-same-itemssource-of-observablecollectioncomboboxitem)

Comment: This is expected, when you are switching the contents are detached from visual tree and they are not visible, you need to attach them back in order to see the content again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any visual elements such as `ListBoxItem` to the source collection. Add `strings` instead and you will get the expected results:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Int32 i = 0;
    private ObservableCollection<string> components = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Components
    {
        get
        {
            if (components == null)
                components = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            return components;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Components.Add("Part " + i.ToString());
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

A visual element can only appear *once* in the visual tree. This basically means that the `ListBoxItem` that you add to the first `ListBox` cannot be displayed in the second `ListBox` and vice versa.